# TeamCity won't build class library with no app.config

Tags: c#, configuration, teamcity

So I have a project (a very simple class library) which I am building. This library makes some calls on an outside resource which depends on a particular connection string.  I've placed this connection string in an app.config file.

However I do not wish to place this app.config file in source control for reasons of key security, so the file has been 'ignored'.

Unfortunately, when TeamCity then attempts to build the library, it complains that it `Could not copy the file "App.config" because it was not found.` The project does build and execute unit tests just fine from my development environment.

I'm certain that I've got the basic ideas right (putting the string in a file, not putting that file into source control), but I think I've missed something with regard how this should be set up.

What are some options I have for getting this library built with TeamCity?

Comment: Shouldn't you put your keys in the config file of the applications using the class library and not the class library's?

Comment: I don't know.  Perhaps.  I can see the argument, but it seems unclear to me how to express this dependency to the consuming applications.  And doesn't this leave me in the same difficulty where unit tests (well, functional tests) are concerned?  If the tests are responsible for housing the config file, and I don't save the file to source control, aren't I back in the same boat?  Same question really for the real application too....

Comment: Maybe it should not be a class library at all. To me it seems more like an API endpoint which can have a special access to an external resource but its callers do not have that access and can only invoke it and get the results back.

Comment: I hear what you're saying, but the team thinks this approach fits our needs better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a workable solution:

Create a new powershell build step in team city
copy the following powershell code into the build step, and set the new build step to execute before the MSBuild step.

```
## first, set the directory to the place where the file lives
Set-Location %teamcity.build.checkoutDir%\RecordingProvider\RecordingProvider

## copy the existing template file into a real app.config file
Copy-Item App.template.config -destination App.config

If (Test-Path App.config){
  ##File exists
  Write-Output "App.config exists"
  exit 0
}Else{
  ## File does not exist
  Write-Error "App.config does not exist!!"
  exit -1
}
```

Just like that, TeamCity now compiles the builds.

I expect there are some other solutions too, but this will get me by until I see them.